# regex match specific symbol ' - " ( ) * , . : … ; ? `

Tags: php, regex, symbols, pos-tagger

I want to build a regex that will tag these specific symbol as "SYM". Therefore, I am building a regex in php which will match this specific symbol ONLY.Is there any regex which accepts these symbol?

```
'   -   "   (   )  *  ,  .   :  …  ;  ?  `
```

The output should be like this:
' \SYM
- \SYM
" \SYM
( \SYM
) \SYM & so on...

This is my programme but it doesn't work :

```
<?php 
 $str = "'this' is Mary! (a dog - not a human)";
 $split = explode(" ",$str);
      foreach($split as $value) {
         $match = array();
         $count = preg_match_all("/\!/|\'/|\-/",$value,$match);
           if ($count != 0)
              $text = "\SYM";
          else
              $text = "\not SYM";
   echo "<br>".$count." ".$value." ".$text;
}
?>
```

Comment: See https://ideone.com/f0k9SZ, is it what you are looking for? If not, what is the expected output for `'this' is Mary! (a dog - not a human)` string?

Comment: show the expected result for the input `"'this' is Mary! (a dog - not a human)"`

Comment: sorry for the delay. The expected result for the input should be like this : '\SYM   this\not SYM  '\SYM  is\not SYM  Mary\not SYM   !\SYM  (\SYM  a\not SYM   dog\not SYM   -\SYM   not\not SYM a\not SYM human\not SYM  )\SYM   "\SYM

Comment: That means you also need to handle `!` as SYM, but you did not mention that in the question. Do you just want to add SYM after any *punctuation* and not SYM after any word?

Comment: sorry for my mistake. I don't need ! in the specific symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code may be as simple as

```
<?php
$in = "'this' is Mary! (a dog - not a human)";
$out = preg_replace('/([-\'"()*,.:…;?`])/', '\1\\SYM ', $in);
echo $out;
```

the regex `/([-'"()*,.:…;?])/` matches each of your special chars and captures it for later use, but take care: the dash (`-`) *should be the first* in the character class to avoid creating ranges, the single quote needs to be escaped (for PHP). The replacement simply replaces the capture (first capturing parenthesis from the left, so `\1`) with itself and appends the string *\SYM* and a *whitespace*. if you need more whitespaces around your replacement, you can alter the replacement string to something like `' \1\\SYM '` or '`\1 \\SYM '` or even `' \1 \\SYM '`

A more "sophisticated" (or elegant, or nerdy) method using lookarounds looks pretty much the same:

```
$out = preg_replace('/(?<=[-\'"()*,.:…;?`])/', '\SYM ', $in);
```

the major difference is, that it does not capture the special char but matches right *BEHIND* one. Note that only a ***position*** is matched here, this position (imagine it as an empty string) gets replaced by your mark - effectively just *inserting* your mark

Both approaches deliver the same output:

```
'\SYM this'\SYM  is Mary! (\SYM a dog -\SYM  not a human)\SYM
```

Comment: sorry for the delay. The expected result for the input should be like this : '\SYM this\not SYM '\SYM is\not SYM Mary\not SYM !\SYM (\SYM a\not SYM dog\not SYM -\SYM not\not SYM a\not SYM human\not SYM )\SYM "\SYM

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew answered according to your rephrased question, imho his solution is correct and i would have done it roughly the same way, so i don't bother updating my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is to tokenize a string into chunks that are punctuation (those `SYM` ones) and the chunks consisting of other characters (excluding whitespace, those `not SYM` ones).

Use

```
$sym_rx = "~(?:([^-'\"()*,.:…;?`\s]+)|([-'\"()*,.:…;?`]))(\s)*~u";
$str = "'this' is Mary! (a dog - not a human)";
echo preg_replace_callback($sym_rx, function ($m) {
    $ins = !empty($m[2]) ? $m[2] . "\\SYM" : $m[1] . "\\not SYM";
    return !empty($m[3]) ? $ins . $m[3] : $ins . " ";
}, $str);
// => '\SYM this\not SYM '\SYM is\not SYM Mary!\not SYM (\SYM a\not SYM dog\not SYM -\SYM not\not SYM a\not SYM human\not SYM )\SYM
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/iVBON1)

Comment: If you do not need the `!`, just use the character class and its reverse negated counterpart.

Comment: See the updated demo. The pattern has the same strcuture, just the symbols from your predefined set are used.

Comment: @shequin Actually, the answer you marked as accepted does not yield the result you wrote you expected.

Comment: may i know what is the function ($m)? I need explanation on how it works. i am sorry,i am a beginner

Comment: With `function($m)`, we define an [*anonymous* (with no name) callback function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). The `$m` argument is [*an array of matched elements in the subject string*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php). Inside the function body, we may do any manipulations to the *match*, access groups, shuffle them, call any other functions on the match, etc.